# Build html tree from data array, but getting duplicates nodes

Tags: php, php-5.3

```
public function buildHtmlTree2($data, $pid = 0)
{
    $str = '<ul>';
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $op = array();
        foreach( $data as $item )
        {
            $str .= '<li>';
            $str .= $item['login'];
            $str .= '</li>';
            if( $item['parent_id'] == $pid )
            {
                $children =  $this->buildHtmlTree2( $data, $item['id'] );
                if( $children ) {
                    $str .= $children;
                }
            }
        }

        $str .= '</ul>';
        return $str;


    }
}
```

input array:

```
array(

  [0] = array(

    'id' => 1,
    'login' => 'test1',
    'parent_id' => 0

  ),
  [1] = array(

    'id' => 2,
    'login' => 'test2',
    'parent_id' => 1

  ),
  [2] = array(

    'id' => 3,
    'login' => 'test3',
    'parent_id' => 1

  )

)
```

i'am passing it an array of `id`, `login` , `parent_id`, but in the output I get duplicates entries, I've tried to unset `$data[$key]` and pass it as a reference, but I think this is not a good way, how to avoid duplicates in this function, what I have to add/edit? can't fingure it out this moment

Answer (score 0):

```
public function buildHtmlTree2($data, $pid = 0)
{
    $str = '<ul>';
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $op = array();
        foreach( $data as $item )
        {
            if( $item['parent_id'] == $pid )
            {
            $str .= '<li>';
            $str .= $item['login'];
            $str .= '</li>';
                $children =  $this->buildHtmlTree2( $data, $item['id'] );
                if( $children ) {
                    $str .= $children;
                }
            }
        }

        $str .= '</ul>';
        return $str;


    }
}
```

I've found the solution, here the code...